# Peewee: getting random records, with an specific seed

Tags: python, random, peewee

The peewee [documentation](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#getting-random-records) explains how to get a random record from a table:

```
Table.select().order_by(fn.Random())
```

however, I want to reproduce the result for a series of tests.

I've checked that in SQL exists the function *setseed*, but it does not work, if I use it like this:

```
Table.select(fn.setseed(1)).order_by(fn.Random())
```

returning the error:

> peewee.OperationalError: no such function: setseed

An additional workaround would be to use the native random module of python and select a random id of the table.
Nevertheless, I wonder if it is possible to set the seed.

I am using Python 2.7, Peewee 2.10 and SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not have a SETSEED function or anything like that:

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html